# Increment/decrement UIstepper value from a preset value

Tags: ios8

I have 2 viewcontrollers, I'm passing an integer value from firstviewcontroller to secondviewcontroller. In secondviewcontroller I'm having a label that displays the passed value. Now im having a UIstepper at the secondviewcontroller, which when clicked i need to increment/decrement the label value which is alredy initialized. 
I've tried many methods. When i clicks decrement the label gives me 0, but i want `labelvalue-1` and on increment `labelvalue+1`.

Comment: Show some code. Are you sure that the value passed is correct one (not zero)?

Comment: Yes, its not zero because the label displays the correct value when the view loads(say 10). But when i clicks the stepper to decrement it directly gives 0 instead of 9.

Comment: Sorry..Made some mistake in initialising the mystepper.value. Now it's ok.